# Loop through all cells in all rows in a table

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to loop through all the `<td>` in each `<tr>` in this table in order to assign a value to each `<td>`.

```html
    <table id="grid">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="4" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="7" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="8" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="9" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="10" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="11" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="12" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="13" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="14" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="15" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="16" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="17" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="18" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="19" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="20" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="21" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="22" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="23" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="24" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="25" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="26" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="27" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="28" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="29" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="30" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="31" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="32" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="33" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="34" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="35" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="36" /></td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="37" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="38" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="39" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="40" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="41" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="42" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="43" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="44" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="45" /></td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="46" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="47" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="48" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="49" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="50" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="51" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="52" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="53" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="54" /></td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="55" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="56" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="57" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="58" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="59" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="60" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="61" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="62" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="63" /></td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="64" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="65" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="66" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="67" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="68" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="69" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="70" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="71" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="72" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="73" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="74" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="75" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="76" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="77" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="78" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="79" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="80" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="81" /></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

So far I've tried this:

```js
     const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
     const row = grid.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     const cell = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    
     for(row in grid) {
         for(cell in row) {
             cell.textContent = "1";
    
         }
     }
```

But it errors with `TypeError: row.getElementsByTagName is not a function`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `row` isn't element, it's collection. Move `const cell = ...` inside `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('td')` to get all of your cells and then you can loop through it by using `forEach` for example.

```js
// looping through the inputs inside the cells
// to demonstrate that it works I log the id of the input field

document.querySelectorAll('td > input').forEach((x) => {
console.log(x.id)
})


// here looping through the cells
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((x) => {
console.log(x)
})
```

```html
<table id="grid">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="6" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="7" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="8" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="9" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="11" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="12" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="13" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="14" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="15" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="16" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="17" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="18" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="19" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="20" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="21" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="22" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="23" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="24" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="25" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="26" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="27" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="28" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="29" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="30" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="31" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="32" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="33" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="34" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="35" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="36" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="37" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="38" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="39" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="40" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="41" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="42" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="43" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="44" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="45" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="46" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="47" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="48" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="49" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="50" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="51" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="52" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="53" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="54" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="55" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="56" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="57" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="58" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="59" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="60" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="61" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="62" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="63" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="64" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="65" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="66" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="67" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="68" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="69" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="70" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="71" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="72" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="73" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="74" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="75" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="76" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="77" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="78" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="79" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="80" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="81" /></td>
        
      </tr>

      

      
    
  </table>
```